# Given a line, how can I apply this transformation mathematically?

Tags: geometry

I'm working on something that uses grid geometry, where lines may only land on grid points and everything in a point's Moore Neighborhood is considered to be distance 1 from the point. Given a line from the origin with length 1 in this geometry, how can I determine the coordinates of the transformed line? I can do it for every one of the 8 states individually, but I'm wondering if there is a general solution so that I can abstract it to different geometries.

The transformation I need is one in which when a line hits a grid point, it rotates 45 degrees counter clockwise and continues to the next grid point.

e.g if my line was defined by $\Big((0,0),(1,1)\Big)$ the resulting line would be $\Big((1,1),(1,2)\Big)$, and if the transformation was applied to the new line, it would yield $\Big((1,2),(0,3)\Big)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a strictly algebraic transform, given a line of length $1$ connecting two grid points:
$$\big((x_0, y_0), (x_1, y_1)\big)$$
Let
$$u=x_1-x_0$$and$$v=y_1-y_0$$
The next line will be:
$$\big((x_1,y_1),(x_1+u-v+\frac{u^2v-v^2u}{2},y_1+v+u-\frac{u^2v+v^2u}{2})\big)$$

Comment: What modifications would I have to make if I wanted a -45 degree turn?

Comment: I believe changing all signs (+/-) in final line should do that.

btw, I corrected a sign error not too long ago.

Comment: I'm getting some erroneous results, for a line from $(0,0)$ to some grid point in the Moore Neighborhood, the generated results should at most have an $\mid{2}\mid$ factor, but my output is getting some $\mid{3}\mid$s

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. Which (+/-) I should change ?

Comment: Change all of them.

Comment: That's causing a 135 degree rotation instead of -45

Comment: After testing, I find the first sign in both coordinate expressions remains positive.

Comment: So to be clear, negate everything except for $x_1 y_1$?

Comment: To be clear, the signs following $x_1$ and $y_1$ remains the same and ALL other signs are switched.

Answer (score 1):

The points that are connected by your line segments satisfy the recurrence relation $x^{i+1} = x^i + A(x^i - x^{i-1})$, where $A$ is the rotation matrix
$$A =\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix},$$
with $\theta=\pi/4$.

Comment: Any links that could help me understand? I'm familiar with matrices and complex numbers but I don't really understand what you're getting at. Specifically, what is $x$?

Comment: I suggest you try it numerically. The part $x^i - x^{i-1}$ is the current direction, and multiplying it with the [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) $A$ gives the new direction. You can verify that $A$ 'works' by multiplying $A$ with the vectors $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

Comment: Ahhh so $x$ is the angle of the new line?

Comment: $x^i$ are the points; in your example they are $x^0 = (0,0)$, $x^1 = (1,1)$, $x^2 = (1,2)$, etc.

Comment: so $A(x_i-x_{i-1})$ is matrix-vector multiplication?

Comment: that is correct; also I prefer to use superscript to index vectors and subscript to index elements of vectors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79817/discussion-between-user189728-and-linalg).

Comment: you never responded in the chat